# How to handle duplicate-posting user?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, users

Check out [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755133/sachitad?tab=questions&sort=newest) who just keeps asking the same question(s) over and over.  He gets responses to the various incarnations but seems incapable of helping himself get past both the immediate problems and the whole project he's working on, reposting questions, or chaining them together.

In the long view he's very gradually working through some rsync-type task by taking the answer from each question and posting each answer afresh as a new question seeking the next step. Step-by-step I guess he'll get there eventually but it does seem to be creating a bit of irritation to me in the process.

Is this kind of behaviour good/bad/reformable/just-get-over-it?

Comment: Bad. Just downvote and he will be eventually banned from asking further questions. You can add comment like "-1 because you don't seem to make any effort on your side" when you downvote.

Comment: flag them as duplicates of the question he just previously asked

Comment: Wow, 37 questions in 49 days... surprised he hasn't run into the question limit yet.

Answer (score 9):

New users who refuse to get it will be subject to [a question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) pretty quickly.

Users like the one you refer to, however, who are still able to actively post questions, are probably either really lucky or really good at skirting the line at which the ban kicks in. In such cases, flagging one of the reposted questions for moderator attention is the most effective solution. You may want to include links to the reposted questions to make it easier for us to review.

In this case, since you've posted here already, I've gone ahead and sent the user a warning, so no further action is needed unless the user refuses to heed; in which case a suspension may be warranted.